# MySQL Syntax Error on INSERT Query

Tags: php, mysql

Running a MySQL INSERT query, where the only 3 dynamic variables are an e-mail address and 2 date('Y-m-d H:i:s') fields.

I'm getting the error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIST_SUBSCRIBER' at line 1

My Query:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

INSERT INTO subscriber_table (
  list_subscriber, user_subscriber, robot_subscriber, date_subscriber,
  update_subscriber, visibility_subscriber, reception_subscriber,
  subscribed_subscriber, included_subscriber
)
VALUES (
  'newsletter', $email, 'listserv.valoans.com', $today, $today, 'conceal', 'mail', '1', '0'
)
```

All SELECT queries work correctly.

Comment: Do you need to put quotes around `$email` in your query? You could also switch to using a prepared statement, which takes care of that sort of thing for you.

Comment: and quotes around the $today dates as well. `2013-08-31` is going to be interepreted as a 3-term arithmetic subtraction, and end up being `1974`. `'2013-08-31'` (note the quotes) will be treated as a date (or at least a string).

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subscriber_table(list_subscriber, user_subscriber,
                                     robot_subscriber, date_subscriber,
                                     update_subscriber, visibility_subscriber, 
                                     reception_subscriber, subscribed_subscriber,
                                     included_subscriber)
        VALUES('newsletter', '$email', 'listserv.valoans.com',
               '$today', '$today', 'conceal', 'mail',' 1', '0')";
```

Also, make sure you escape `$email` first, with:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```

However, it would be better if you used mysqli or PDO, which support parametrized queries instead of interpolating into strings.